# How could i make it so if i divide 2 variables together, it always rounds up?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm making a program that encrypts a piece of text given, or does it off of a file. The encryption method i'm trying to use involves reading the key, converting it from text to an ASCII value. It then appends it into a variable called Offsets.

```
for i in range(KeyLength):
  Offsets.append(ord(Key[i]))
EncryptionLength = len(EncryptionText)
```

What i'm trying to do is to divide the EncryptionText by the KeyLength. If it returns a decimal, i want it to round up. I've tried using // but i'm kind of stumped.

Comment: You might want this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/number_ceil.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [math.**ceil**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil):

```
>>> import math
>>> EncryptionText = 'abcdefghijkl' # 12 characters
>>> EncryptionLength = 5
>>> len(EncryptionText)/EncryptionLength)
2.4
>>> math.ceil(len(EncryptionText)/EncryptionLength))
3
```